# Apache Redirects and slash problems

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a rewrite set up that directs a second domain to a first domain via a 301. However, whenever I go to seconddomain.com or www.seconddomain.com in my browser, I end up at http://www.firstdomain.com//

Notice the two slashes?!? Driving me crazy. How can I avoid this?

---

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.firstdomain.com
        ServerAlias firstdomain.com *.firstdomain.com
        DocumentRoot /opt/firstdomain.com/static
        <Directory /opt/firstdomain.com/static>
                Allow from all
                Options -MultiViews

                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.seconddomain.com
        ServerAlias seconddomain.com *.seconddomain.com
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.firstdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the URI's that are used in a virtualhost context *has a leading slash*, unlike URI's that are passed through rules in an htaccess file. You need to change your rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.firstdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks! This seemed to do it (or maybe it was one of the other 30 tweaks I've tried this morning) :)